# (Why) does FreeBSD 'net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive' violate RFC1122?

Tags: freebsd, tcp, keepalive

While working on a server application that runs on FreeBSD and uses TCP, I noticed that TCP keepalive probes get
sent even though my application explicitly disables SO_KEEPALIVE on TCP sockets.

According to [RFC1122 Section 4.2.3.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-101) (TCP Keep-Alives):

> "If keep-alives are included, the application MUST be able to turn
> them on or off for each TCP connection, and they MUST default to off."

I found that the tuneable parameter **net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive** had been enabled (set to 1), and that disabling it would stop the keepalive probes from being sent.

What is the reasoning behind the inclusion of this behaviour in FreeBSD? From what I can tell, Linux and Windows do not have such an option, but FreeBSD and Mac OS X do, so they violate the RFC.

To be more specific, under what circumstance would it make sense to ignore the application's wishes?

This is a straightforward fix in my case as I can disable the option, but I'd like to understand why it's there.

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/497118/is-tcp-keepalive-application-dependant-on-linux) shows that Linux behaves according to the RFC.

Comment: In Linux, net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time provides similar functionality, and I'm sure windows has an option, just called something different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rationale for turning keep-alive on by default was given here: https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=47752

> Add handle to control global TCP keepalives and turn them on as
>   default.
>
> Despite their name it doesn't keep TCP sessions alive, it kills them
>   if the other end has gone AWOL.  This happens a lot with clients which
>   use NAT, dynamic IP assignment or which has a 2^32
>   * 10^-3 seconds upper bound on their uptime.
>
> There is no detectable increase in network trafic because of this: two
>   minimal TCP packets every two hours for a live TCP connection.
>
> Many servers already enable keepalives themselves.
>
> The host requirements RFC is 10 years old, and doesn't know about the
>   loosing clients of todays InterNet.

Anyway it is better to turn keep-alive off if requested by application, for example (in C):

```
int val = 0;
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &val, sizeof(val));
```

but it is not easy to fix this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the rationale in that commit message, and agree that it's better to do what the application asks for. As you say, it wouldn't be easy to fix this as many existing server configurations probably rely on the current behaviour.

Comment: For reference, I found the [original commit message](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=15039) for the sysctl.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tunable knob should exist but perhaps it was better to keep it off by default.

My reasoning is this, a application developer can get these sort of decisions wrong and ultimately a sysadmin, should have control over this sort of network policy not the application developer.

Comment: I don't understand this answer ...